# SQL: Count number of columns in a row that fall within a certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 20 rows, 10 are labelled `A1, A2, A3, ...A10` and the other 10 are G1, G2,.etc.

They hold integers between the values of 0 & 99.

I want to select only the rows that have x (say 4) number of columns that have a value that falls within a certain range, 50 - 70 for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean 20 *columns* ?

Comment: Yes sorry, 20 columns.

Comment: could you describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: Yes it's going to be painful though. Lots of sql, a pivot, or normalise the data (value per row). Need the full table structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you would do it with a brute force approach:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             ((case when a1 between 50 and 70 then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when a2 between 50 and 70 then 1 else 0 end) +
              . . .
              (case when a10 between 50 and 70 then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when g1 between 50 and 70 then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when g2 between 50 and 70 then 1 else 0 end) +
              . . .
              (case when g10 between 50 and 70 then 1 else 0 end)
             ) n
      from t
     ) t
where n = 4;
```

You need to fill in the `. . .` with the same logic for the remaining columns.

Comment: Brute force works for me...cheers!